# Standard Version changelog repeats changes in different releases

Tags: release, git-tag, changelog, conventional-commits

I'm using `standard-version` with `conventional commits` to manage releases of an app i'm working on, and I'm having trouble with the auto generation of the Changelog.

Basically what happens is that every time I do a new release, it puts in the changelog not only the changes of the current release but also the ones of the previous, like so:

```
0.0.2
Features
- feature 1
- feature 2

0.0.1
Features
- feature 1
```

Since I'm in `beta` this is the command that I run: `npm run release -- --prerelease beta`

Any good advice on generating a lighter changelog?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you do a release, you also need to create a tag. For example

`git tag -a v0.0.1 -m'First beta release'`

then, the next time you run
`npm run release -- --prerelease beta`

`standard-version` will only add the changes since the last tag, and you end up with

```
0.0.2
Features
- feature 2

0.0.1
Features
- feature 1
```

You have to make sure that you have your tags available locally.
When you run the release.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `standard-version` makes a git tag when you run `npm run release`.

I never tagged the repo manually but I see a list of all our releases when I check for tags:

```
matteo ⸫ aws-amplify-multi-tenant (develop) $ git tag
v0.1.0
v0.1.1
v0.1.1-alpha.0
v0.1.1-beta.0
v0.1.1-beta.1
v0.1.1-beta.10
v0.1.1-beta.11
v0.1.1-beta.2
v0.1.1-beta.3
v0.1.1-beta.4
v0.1.1-beta.5
v0.1.1-beta.6
v0.1.1-beta.7
v0.1.1-beta.8
v0.1.1-beta.9
```